# Filtering results between two dates with rdlc report in asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

- I am using RDLC for reports loaded into ASP.NET MVC.
- I tried to filter the results between two dates, but when I type the following query below I get the following error:

> "the new command text returns data with schema different from the schema of the main query. Check your query's command text if this is not desired."

Can you help me on how to do it?

```
SELECT
    SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemId,
    SiparisKalems.Siparisid,
    SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemTarih,
    SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemAdet,
    SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemFiyat,
    SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemToplam,
    SiparisKalems.Urunid, 
    Uruns.Urunid AS Expr1,
    Uruns.UrunAdi,
    Uruns.UrunFiyat,
    Uruns.UrunGorsel,
    Uruns.Kategoriid,
    Uruns.Durum
FROM
    SiparisKalems
    INNER JOIN Uruns ON SiparisKalems.Urunid = Uruns.Urunid
WHERE
    (
        SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemTarih >= @Param1
        AND
        SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemTarih <= @Param2
    )
ORDER BY
    SiparisKalems.SiparisKalemTarih DESC
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SiparisKalems](
    [SiparisKalemId]     [int]            NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Siparisid]          [int]            NOT NULL,
    [SiparisKalemTarih]  [datetime]       NOT NULL,
    [SiparisKalemAdet]   [int]            NOT NULL,
    [SiparisKalemFiyat]  [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [SiparisKalemToplam] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Urunid]             [int]            NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_dbo.SiparisKalems PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [SiparisKalemId] ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_dbo.SiparisKalems_dbo.Siparislers_Siparisid ([Siparisid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Siparislers] ([Siparisid]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.SiparisKalems_dbo.Uruns_Urunid] FOREIGN KEY([Urunid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Uruns] ([Urunid]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Uruns](
    [Urunid]      [int]               NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [UrunAdi]     [varchar](30)       NOT NULL,
    [UrunFiyat]   [decimal](18, 2)    NOT NULL,
    [UrunGorsel]  [varchar](250)      NOT NULL,
    [Kategoriid]  [int]               NOT NULL,
    [Durum]       [bit]               NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Uruns] PRIMARY KEY ( [Urunid] ),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Uruns_dbo.Kategoris_Kategoriid] FOREIGN KEY([Kategoriid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Kategoris] ([Kategoriid]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: SQL does not care about C# classes, instead please post your `CREATE TABLE` statements. As you're using EF you'll need to use `SSMS's Object Explorer > Script as CREATE` tool.

Comment: Since I created the database with the codefirst approach and turned on automatic migrations, I wrote the classes. Since I don't know sql queries, I tried to filter automatically in dataset. In Dataset, filter part of OrderItemDate >=?AND<=? I wrote it and it gave this query itself. Where do I need to fix?

Comment: "Since I created the database with the codefirst approach and turned on automatic migrations, I wrote the classes." - correct, that's why I asked you to use SSMS to generate the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: but I already have my tables. I don't understand why I should use create table. https://www.hizliresim.com/9btweq7

Comment: Because **we** (other StackOverflow users) don't know what EF did to create your database, so for us to see your table structure as-used by SQL Server you need to use the "Script Table As... CREATE To" menu option to generate the SQL which you can then copy-and-paste to StackOverflow so we can see it. I am not asking you to re-create the tables, just to show us the SQL definition of the tables (which is called a "`CREATE TABLE` statement").

Comment: I get it now. Sorry for bothering you. I'm editing my question now.

Comment: Please post your RDLC report definition. How is the `SELECT` query being generated?